# comparing a matrix with irregular number of columns per row with a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a main file that has about 41k rows (entries) with a variable number of columns per row.

```
AC_peg_0698__[locus_tag=Adeh_0700]  Bac_export_2    
AC_peg_0699__[locus_tag=Adeh_0701]  Bac_export_1    
AC_peg_0700__[locus_tag=Adeh_0702]  Bac_export_3    
AC_peg_0701__[locus_tag=Adeh_0703]  FliP    
AC_peg_0702__[locus_tag=Adeh_0704]  FliO    
AC_peg_0703__[locus_tag=Adeh_0705]  FliMN_C 
AC_peg_0704__[locus_tag=Adeh_0706]  YscJ_FliF   
AC_peg_0705__[locus_tag=Adeh_0707]  No_Domain   
AC_peg_0706__[locus_tag=Adeh_0708]  No_Domain
.
.
.
AC_peg_1378__[locus_tag=Adeh_1382]  CheR_N  CheR    
AC_peg_1379__[locus_tag=Adeh_1383]  Response_reg    CheB_methylest  
AC_peg_1380__[locus_tag=Adeh_1384]  MotB_plug   OmpA    
AC_peg_1381__[locus_tag=Adeh_1385]  MotA_ExbB   
AC_peg_1382__[locus_tag=Adeh_1386]  FlbD    
AC_peg_1383__[locus_tag=Adeh_1387]  Flg_bb_rod  FlaE    Flg_bbr_C   
AC_peg_1384__[locus_tag=Adeh_1388]  FlgD    FlgD_ig
```

i have a list that i have to compare with the above file. there are about 38 elements in this list.

```
Bac_export_1
Bac_export_2
Bac_export_3
Bac_export_4
ChapFlgA
CheC
FHIPEP
Flg_hook
FlgD
FlgD_ig
FlgI
FlgI
FlgM
FlgN
FlhC
FlhD
FlhE
FliD
FliD
FliG
FliH
FliJ
FliL
FliM
FliN_N
FliO
FliP
FliS
FliT
FliW
FliX
Glucosaminidase
MotA_ExbB
MotB_plug
MotY_N
Rod-binding
T3SS_ATPase_C
YscJ_FliF
```

I want to extract all the rows, that match any element from the list.
for example, for the element MotB_plug from the list, i want to extract all the rows that match with it and create a seperate file for it. i want seperate file for each element in the list.

the final file would look somewhat like this:

```
ES114__peg_0708___VF_0715   MotB_plug   OmpA
ES114__peg_2773___VF_A0187  MotB_plug   OmpA
MJ11__peg_0701___VFMJ11_RS10770 MotB_plug   OmpA
MJ11__peg_2789___VFMJ11_RS01075 MotB_plug   OmpA
SR5__peg_0707___VFSR5_RS03610   MotB_plug   OmpA
SR5__peg_2770___VFSR5_RS14190   MotB_plug   OmpA
LFI1238__peg_0951___VSAL_RS05180    MotB_plug   OmpA
```

this file has extracted all the entries with motB_plug

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BBT31zcsXGP9-N2gRoJ5wdWkHrq6LT1r?usp=sharing

these are my files for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not super efficient but does the job:

```py
with open("protein_domain.txt") as f:
    lst = list()
    for el in f:
        lst.append(el.strip())

 
for pattern in lst:
    with open(f"{pattern}.txt", "w") as new_file:
        with open("data.txt") as f:
            for line in f:
                if pattern in line:
                    new_file.write(line)
```

For more effective but cumulative result:

```sh
grep -E "Bac_export_1|Bac_export_2|Bac_export_3|Bac_export_4|ChapFlgA|CheC|FHIPEP|Flg_hook|FlgD|FlgD_ig|FlgI|FlgI|FlgM|FlgN|FlhC|FlhD|FlhE|FliD|FliD|FliG|FliH|FliJ|FliL|FliM|FliN_N|FliO|FliP|FliS|FliT|FliW|FliX|Glucosaminidase|MotA_ExbB|MotB_plug|MotY_N|Rod-binding|T3SS_ATPase_C|YscJ_FliF" data.txt > output.txt
```